# condition statement to display particular block in python pandas only when the file is present

Tags: pandas

I have written a code that will list out the scenarios which have a greater value from the given files. and I want to change the code as if the particular file is not present at the moment it should skip the block and move on to next block, but now the code shows an error if some of the files not present.

Here's my code:

```
Path ="/Users/xyz"

1regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/11regressions.csv")
1regressions = 1regressions[(1regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (1regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
1regressions['filename']='11regressions.csv'
1regressions = 1regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]


2regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/12regressions.csv")
2regressions = 2regressions[(2regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (2regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
2regressions['filename']='12regressions.csv'
2regressions = 2regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]



3regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/13regressions.csv")
3regressions = 3regressions[(3regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (3regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
3regressions['filename']='13regressions.csv'
3regressions = 3regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]


4regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/14regressions.csv")
4regressions = 4regressions[(4regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (4regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
4regressions['filename']='14regressions.csv'
4regressions = 4regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]

5regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/15regressions.csv")
5regressions = 5regressions[(5regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (5regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
5regressions['filename']='15regressions.csv'
5regressions = 5regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]
5regressions = 5regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]

6regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/16regressions.csv")
6regressions = 6regressions[(6regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (6regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
6regressions['filename']='16regressions.csv'
6regressions = 6regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]

7regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/17regressions.csv")
7regressions = 7regressions[(7regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (7regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
7regressions['filename']='17regressions.csv'
7regressions = 7regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]

8regressions = pd.read_csv(Path+"/18regressions.csv")
8regressions = 8regressions[(8regressions['tp50_pct'] > 0.15) | (JPH_regressions['tp90_pct'] > 0.15)]
8regressions['filename']='18regressions.csv'
8regressions = 8regressions[['filename','metric_type','content_format','tp50_pct', 'tp90_pct','mean_pct','iterations','perf_run_id','baseline_perf_run_id']]


result = 1regressions.append([2regressions, 3regressions,4regressions,5regressions,6regressions,7regressions,8regressions])
result.index = range(1, len(result) + 1)
result.to_csv(r'/Users/xyz/test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.exists`.

But first, put all the repeated code in a loop.

```
dfs = []
Path =`.../xyz/'
for filename in list_with_filenames:
    if os.path.exists(Path + filename): # this is what you were missing
        df = pd.read_ csv(Path + filename)
        # modify df
       dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```